# Find the control points in 3D space of a 2D Bézier mapped on the parametric space of a (3D) Bézier patch

Tags: geometry, surfaces, bezier-curve

I was able to solve this for a Bézier curve of order 1 on a bicubic patch (it is a Bézier curve of order 6 [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCnUt.jpg) ) But for higher degree curves I couldn't find anything. The question is too long for search engines. I know CAD softwares does it (hopefully without approximations/solver), it must be inside some paper like most of CAD maths, or am I missing something ?

Comment: If you know how to solve that in a plane, you can rotate your curve to a xy plane and then rotate back the solution.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I might not have been clear, the 2D coordinates are the UV coordinates of the parametric space of the surface

Comment: The word “Bézier” is a man’s name. Given the contributions he made, he deserves to have his name capitalized and spelled correctly. I fixed a few occurrences. Maybe you could fix the others by copy/paste.

Comment: @bubba yes my bad I agree. I pray at him every evening those days x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll suggest two possible approaches …

First approach: Convert your curve and surface from Bézier-Bernstein form into power basis (monomial) form. Suppose the surface is $(u,v) \mapsto S(u,v)$ and the curve is $t \mapsto (u(t),v(t))$. Then you can just substitute the curve equation into the surface equation, and you’ll get a 3D curve equation $t \mapsto S(u(t),v(t))$, again in power basis form. Now convert that curve back to Bézier-Bernstein form. The point is that doing function composition is much easier in the power basis than the Bernstein basis, though it’s still a huge mess of algebra. I’d recommend you get a computer algebra system, like Mathematica or Maple to help.

Second approach. If the surface has degrees $m \times n$ and the 2D curve has degree $p$, then you know the final result is a 3D Bézier curve of degree $k = mp + np$. So calculate $k+1$ points on the 3D curve, and interpolate them with a Bézier curve of degree $k$. For simplicity, you can calculate points $Q_0, Q_1, \ldots, Q_k$ at parameter values $\tau_i = i/k$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,k$. Then you need to construct a Bézier curve $C$ that has $C(\tau_i) = Q_i$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,k$. Of course, you do this just by solving a linear system of equations to find the control points. If you always use the same $\tau_i$ values, then the matrix of the linear system is fixed, and you can just invert it once (perhaps exactly), and then re-use it over and over again.

Also, it might help to read my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720398/nurbs-curves-to-interpolate-points-and-derivatives-on-a-surface-of-revolution) (and maybe the papers I cited).

If you want to try doing the function composition in the Bernstein basis, then [this paper](https://inria.hal.science/hal-01708592/document) provides some relevant formulas, though I find it pretty hard to read, personally.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds amazing! I am pretty sure I can manage to implement the second method.

Comment: And I think I tried the first method without success because yes, manually it is a mess

Comment: The first method is horrible unless you use a computer algebra system. The second method is easy, especially if you already have code to do the interpolation.